# Overriding property return type, C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have class like this

```
public class A: SomeClass
{
    public TimeZoneInfo Timezone { get; set; }
    public A()
    {
        Timezone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    }
}
```

I have another class like this:

```
public class B: A
{
    public string Timezone { get; set; }
    public B()
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I want to override the return type of TimeZone Property in class B.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return type cannot be overridden, because return type is part of the fixed part of the method's signature/property type. You can, however, do method/property *hiding* and change the return type using keyword `new`:

```
public new string Timezone { get; set; } //note the new keyword
```

Also, if you want to do overriding, you should put `virtual` keyword in the original (base) `class` and use `override` keyword in the derived `class`:

```
public class A: SomeClass
{
    public virtual TimeZoneInfo Timezone { get; set; } //note virtual keyword
    public A()
    {
        Timezone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
    }
}

public class B: A
{
    public override TimeZoneInfo Timezone { get; set; } //note override keyword, return type is not changed
    public B()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Countdown to his next question about "why are does my codes not timezone" in three, two, one...

Comment: I knew how to override if the return type is same. I was asking if those are different, is it possible or not? I need this because i have found two different property when i am trying to fetching all the property. and It' obvious. When I fetch i need only string type TimeZone.

Comment: and Thanks for your co-operation @Ian

Comment: No, it is *not* possible to override method with the same name but having different return type. The only thing you could do is *hiding* it. Thus, in the upper level, you would get the *string return type*  which you want. But it is not *overriding*, it is called *hiding* - since it does not override the base method/property but completely *overwrite* it with *new* method/property (thus it is called method/property *hiding*). What you seek is likely method/property *hiding*

Answer (score 0):

It's not normally possible to do this, but under some situations, it can be achieved using generics:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public T { get; set;}
    public A() {};
}

public class B: A<TimeZone>
{
    public B() {};
    public void Whatever() 
    {
        T.UtcOffset = 47;
    }
}
public class C: A<string>
{
     public C() {};
     public void Whatever() 
     {
          T = "47";
     }
}
```